# Optiplex 980 are turning on after power loss - how to disable

Tags: dell, electrical-power, bios

We have 24 computers from Dell (Optiplex 980) and there is often a power outage here, a few times a day. It is a small school in a poor country with no stable electricity system.

After the power returns, all computers are automatically turning on and booting the OS, which causes a huge power consumption. In the BIOS, there is an option called `AC Recovery`, where all computers are set to `Power Off`. According to the description, this should keep them off, but still they are turning on automatically.

Is there something I can do? Like doing a BIOS upgrade?

Comment: This should work. Have you *tried* a BIOS upgrade to see if it fixes this? Also check if there is an option like "last state" that would only turn them on again if they where on while losing power.

Comment: Not yet, because the Dell BIOS updater is an executable for Windows, which not starting due to too many power losses and misconfiguration. Will try that later.